# Screen is stuck in Authentication error in tiger VNC's login screen in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I am frequently facing the screen getting stuck in Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS. Can you please help me out here  ?

Let me know if you need more info on this .Thanks